# SSH from host (WSL) to guest qemu VM (linux, aarch64) : Connection closed by remote host error

Tags: linux, ssh, qemu, arm64

I am trying to ssh from my guest machine (WSL) into a QEMU VM, running linux 5.16.10 with default image from Yocto on aarch64 [image core-image-minimal-dev-qemuarm64.ext4 from  http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-3.4/machines/qemu/qemuarm64/ ]

I compiled Linux 5.16.10 locally (it had

`CONFIG_VIRTIO_NET=y CONFIG_E1000=y CONFIG_E1000E=y` by default). Here is the command that I'm running:
`qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,mte=on -cpu max -kernel linux-5.16.10/arch/arm64/boot/Image -hda ../../../Downloads/core-image-minimal-dev-qemuarm64.ext4 -m 2G -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/vda" -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22`

And then I try to ssh using command "ssh -vvv root@localhost -p5555". [Here is the output :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC08m.png)

I also tried a slightly different qemu command - 'qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,mte=on -cpu max -kernel linux-5.16.10/arch/arm64/boot/Image -hda ../../../Downloads/core-image-minimal-dev-qemuarm64.ext4 -m 2G -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/vda" -chardev socket,path=/tmp/port1,server=on,wait=off,id=port1-char -device virtio-serial -device virtserialport,id=port1,chardev=port1-char,name=org.fedoraproject.port.0 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -net nic', but SSH again fails with the same error as above.

**Guest VM details:**

[Here is the dmesg log related to e1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPMRv.png).
Output of running 'uname -a' on the VM : Linux qemuarm64 5.16.10 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 16 22:14:16 EST 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

On the guest VM, I added my local id_rsa.pub file contents to the VM's /etc/ssh/authorized_keys file. [I also manually added a sshd_config file in /etc/ssh folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W4zw.png). I ran 'ps aux | grep ssh' but didn't find anything.

Also ifconfig on the VM only returns lo.

[Output of 'ip link list', 'ip addr list'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lxXb.png)

How can I solve this to successfully ssh from host to guest VM?

Comment: This can't possibly ever work until and unless you set up a NIC inside the guest. It's not enough to create it in the virtual hardware and set up port forwarding; the guest needs to also be aware. So this question is focusing on the wrong things -- there's no reason to believe the setup on the host is wrong; it's the setup _in the guest_ where details are needed but none have been provided.

Comment: In your first qemu invocation, you're setting up an e1000 device. Did you actually load the kernel driver associated with that device in the guest? If you read dmesg from when you load that driver, what hardware (if any) did it say it detected? Which Linux distro are you running in the guest? Which network management tooling does it use? (Common options include systemd-networkd and network-manager, but every distro provides _something_). What did you do to set up those tools?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am using a locally built Linux image, v5.16.10, for arch64. It had CONFIG_E1000 enabled in its config. How do I load the kernel driver for e1000? Also I get 'command not found' when I run systemd, systemd-networkd, network-manager on the VM.

Comment: I get 'command not found' when running systemctl as well. I'm not sure but thats maybe because I'm not running qemu with a full OS, but with just the kernel, i.e. direct kernel boot.

Comment: Okay, if it's fully enabled (`Y` instead of `M`), you shouldn't need to do anything else to enable it at the driver level, so it's just configuration. Does the virtual hardware show up in `lspci`? Any messages from the driver showing whether and how it detected that hardware in `dmesg`?

Comment: We might be in a place where I would need to pull down that ext4 image to figure out what network config facilities it provides. Can't promise I'll have the time, to be honest.

Comment: BTW, in general, I recommend avoiding ifconfig on modern Linux in favor of iproute2 (which provides the `ip` command, and thus can be called with, for example, `ip link list` or `ip addr list`). ifconfig has been unmaintained for something like 15 years now, and it doesn't support new kernel features added in that time.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I have added 'ip link list' output - I see both lo, eth0. I get 'command not found' on running 'lspci', though 'lscpu', 'lsmem' work.

Comment: Okay, great; since eth0 shows up we don't need to worry about lspci: the adapter is there, so any debugging that would be running down why it isn't is moot. :)

Comment: Since `-net user` simulates a DHCP server (IIRC), I think you may be able to use `dhcpcd` or whatever other DHCP client your disk image provides to assign an IP address to eth0.

Comment: BTW, might I suggest setting up your guest to use a serial console so you can have qemu plumb it to stdin/stdout? That way you can copy/paste transcripts as text instead of needing to use screenshot images.

Comment: That makes sense! 'dhcpcd' returns command not found, there's also no dhcp folder in /var/lib [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking does mention a DHCP server on 10.0.2.2]

Comment: It's not _obligatory_ to use DHCP -- if you know the settings that qemu's embedded SLiRP server uses you can set them up by hand using `iproute2` and the like. That said, if this is more than a one-off I'd probably start using some embedded-image-building tools that construct a disk image with whatever software you want, so you _can_ get a DHCP client and anything else you need -- personally in the more distant past I used [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/), and these days I'm an acolyte of [NixOS](https://nixos.org/). Nix is the better tool, but it's got a monster learning curve

Comment: ...so unless you're already reasonably conversant in functional programming (if you know / are comfortable with Haskell, Nix should be no trouble for you), Buildroot is maybe the easier place to start. (Also, if you're trying to target exceptionally small hardware, it's easier to get there out-of-the-box with Buildroot than Nix; you _can_ build a truly minimal system image with Nix, but it's not the use case it's optimized for).

Comment: Thanks! I'll start with trying buildroot for now.

Comment: Ok I built a custom image using buildroot, with BR2_SYSTEM_DHCP="eth0" in the config. Now running the qemu command ' qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,mte=on -cpu max -kernel buildroot2_output/Image -drive file=buildroot2_output/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw -append "rootwait root=/dev/vda" -net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10007-:22 -serial stdio ' . While ssh into the VM is still giving the same error, wget is working (no DNS resolution error), which is sufficient for now. Thanks Charles!